# Running WSGI web server on a port (without using IIS)

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Opening up a port for http request using WSGI (code is in Python+Django) on windows 10 - does not work for http requests coming from another machine

I have a python+django+mongodb site which works great when I run it through VS and now I would like to publish it.

My IIS set up with web.config with fastCGI gone bonkers and I am too frustrated to pursue it for the time being.

Now I decided to run a WSGI server on a port. So here is what I did. I started my app from command line by running my manage.py like this...

```
    C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe manage.py runserver --noreload --settings=myapp.settings
```

And it starts the server and I can visit the site at http://localhost:8000 and everything works great - LOCALLY.

But with my machine IP x.y.z.w - I cannot access it from another machine
by visiting http://x.y.z.w:8000

Why can't my server listens to the port 8000 from another machine on the SAME network?

What do I have to do to allow this?

I am on Windows 10

Comment: Did you setup a hostname ?

Comment: You shouldn't use the dev server for that, even in such a limited circumstance. Use an *actual* WSGI server, ie gunicorn or uWSGI.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try those.

Comment: To answer: Yes I have a hostname...

Comment: I was wondering if I missed any windows configuration - like allowing remote host to connect/send request by http protocol etc. - if there is any such I would love to know them.